How to Use Moto Glue Catalog with Spark SQL for Local Testing?
I'm using Moto to mock AWS Glue for local testing with Spark. I can successfully start Moto with moto_server -p9999 and create databases and tables in Glue. However, when I try to run a Spark SQL command like ss.sql("SELECT * FROM db.table"), it seems to point to the default Spark catalog instead of the mocked Moto Glue catalog.
Here’s my simplified Spark session setup:
implicit val ss: SparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("test spark session")
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
  .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
  .config("spark.hadoop.glue.catalog.enabled", "true")
  .config("spark.hadoop.glue.catalog.catalog-endpoint", "http://localhost:9999")
  .config("spark.hadoop.glue.catalog.region", "us-west-1")
  .config("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.client.factory.class",
          "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

My glueClient is configured to use Moto for local testing:
val glueClient: AWSGlue = {
  AWSGlueClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
    new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
      "http://localhost:9999",
      "us-west-1")
    ).withCredentials(
      new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
        new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey")
      )
    ).build()
}

I’m able to view the databases and tables created through Moto, but Spark SQL queries don't seem to recognize them. How can I configure Spark to use the Moto Glue catalog so that I can run SHOW DATABASES or query tables directly with Spark SQL?

I don't think you can, moto mocks the AWS API calls and afaik Spark uses the Thrift protocol to communicate with the data catalog / hive metastore which is not part of the AWS API that moto covers.

Moto maintainer here - @Maurice is correct, this is not supported by Moto, and out of scope as we only support the AWS API.
